# Pip not installing project with makefiles

Tags: python-3.x, pip, setuptools, distutils, pypi

I want my package to be installable via `pip`, so the user can run `pip install` to install the package. The project uses makefiles to generate a Python module, which I then want to install.

I've already tried subclassing build, so that the makefiles run as a part of `python3 setup.py build`, and the project even gets successfully installed on running `python3 setup.py build install`

current `setup.py`:

```
import distutils.cmd
import distutils.log
import distutils.command.build
import setuptools
import subprocess

class CustomBuildCommand(distutils.cmd.Command):
    description = '  '
    user_options = []
    def initialize_options(self):
        pass
    def finalize_options(self):
        pass
    def run(self):
        cmd = ['make']
        subprocess.check_call(cmd)

class BuildCommand(distutils.command.build.build):
    def run(self):
        self.run_command('customcmd')
        distutils.command.build.build.run(self)

setuptools.setup(
    name='abc',
    version='0.0.1',
    description='xyz',
    install_requires=[],
    packages=['abc'],
    package_data={'abc': ['*']},
    cmdclass={
        'customcmd': CustomBuildCommand,
        'build': BuildCommand,
    }
)
```

But when running `pip3 install .`, it tries running `egg_info` at the start, and fails since the package directories don't exist yet (because the makefiles haven't been run).

I can't figure out how to resolve this, I tried adding all the relevant files into `MANIFEST.in` but to no avail.

Comment: Let's take a step back: This is not a very common pattern, can you explain why you need to generate the Python modules at install-time? Doing this is going to limit you to source distributions only, you won't be able to create a built distribution (like a `.whl` file).

Comment: @DustinIngram I'm generating bindings for python, and they need to be configured and built using the makefiles.